# dual boot lubuntu/windows xp: lubuntu installed first

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, windows-xp

I would like to dual-boot lubuntu 12.04 alongside windows xp on an old IBM thinkpad T42. However, lubuntu was installed first, and I don't want to have to FDisk it, then reinstall everything. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks, -Chris

Comment: 12.04 has just a few days left of support and you shouldn't use XP in 2017 under NO CIRCUNSTANCE. Either keep Lubuntu only (14.04, 16.04) or upgrade your hardware.

Answer (score -1):

Yes absolutely!
First of all, is lubuntu installed using UEFI, as this will be important later? You can tell by looking in your BIOS, and checking if legacy mode or BIOS boot mode is disabled.

I'm guessing since it was windows XP, it's going to be BIOS, but we still need to make sure.

For now, we need to use the Windows installation on your computer. You also need a USB flash drive or CD you can burn for this.

For now, download [Super Grub 2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/).

Next we need to burn it to a bootable medium. Do not use any tools that extract the ISO, as it is a complete disk image that needs to be written directly. You can do this using [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/Archive/). If you've ever used a raspberry pi, then you should be familiar with this tool. Make sure you select All files from the drop down menu so you can see your ISO for SG2D.

Once your device is imaged, boot from the disk. You should be taken to a GRUB bootloader. Just browse through your detected OSes until you find a linux kernel that you know is your lubuntu install.

When you press enter, your system will boot in Verbose mode, without any kind of boot animation. Don't panic! Everything is normal, SG2D just doesn't load plymouth, that provides the boot animation.

When we get into a desktop environment, we need to install boot-repair.

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

then we can launch boot-repair by typing

```
boot-repair
```

then we select the advanced options drop down menu.

Remember earlier, when we needed to know if the system was installed with UEFI? Well we need to know that now.

If lubuntu was installed with UEFI

Your first tab, Main Options, should look like this
[image]

If lubuntu was installed with BIOS your first tab should look like this

[image]

Your last tab should look like this regardless of what mode

[image]

before you click apply, make absolutely sure that the media that contains SG2D is removed from your computer, or you're going to get some weird extra options in your grub menu.

Once you click apply, just follow any prompts it may give you.

Then, you should be good to go! Next time you reboot, you will be given a choice of what OS you want to boot, instead of just booting to either OS.

Comment: No, absolutely not. You shouldn't be helping people in using unsupported OSes.

Comment: 1) I don't think the OP has Windows installed yet, so there's nothing to change in grub yet, and 2) Why go through the trouble of downloading, burning, and booting a new live ISO (super grub disk) and then installing boot-repair, when you can just install boot-repair in Lubuntu?

Comment: Lubuntu 12.04 reached EOL two years ago and Lubuntu 14.04 reaches EOL this month.  Neither should be used.  While Ubuntu is supported for 5 years, the distinct "flavors" are only supported for 3.